# multithreading in C# 5.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-5.0

I have the following requirements:

There are array of urls, which should be downloaded.

1. Only 3 urls can be in process of downloading simultaneously
2. If one (or more) from these 3 urls are completed - need to get next free url from array
3. if one (or more) from these 3 urls are not completed during X time - need to cancel this url
4. If array of urls are finished - we wait to complete all current task and only one go our from main method.

How to do it on C# 5.0? I try to do following:

```
class Program
{
    static Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        string[] urls = new string[] { "http://site1.ru", "http://www.site2.com", "http://site3.com", "http://site4.ru" };
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            var task = AsyncVersion(url);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    static async Task AsyncVersion(string url)
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        Console.WriteLine(
          "Перед вызовом webRequest.GetResponseAsync(). Thread Id: {0}, Url : {1}",
          Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, url);
        var webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}, elapsed {2}ms. Thread Id: {3}", url,
          webResponse.ContentLength, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
          Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    }
}
```

Which parts I don't understand:

1. How to control each thread concrete (not wait only one-by-one or all tasks, but each thread)
2. How long each process are executing...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an ideal job for `Parallel.ForEach()`

You can set the concurrency limit via a parameter, and then use the `WebRequest.Timeout` property to bail after waiting too long for a response.

Something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    urls,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 },
    url =>
    {
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create( url );
            request.Timeout = 10000; // milliseconds
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            // handle response
        }
        catch ( WebException x )
        {
            // timeout or some other problem with the request
        }
        catch ( Exception x )
        {
            // make sure this Action doesn't ever let an exception
            // escape as that would stop the whole ForEach loop
        }
    }
);
```

The call to `Parallel.ForEach()` will block the calling thread until all the urls have been processed.

It will, however, use up to `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` threads to run the work.